# boolean attribute as a string breaks other attributes

Tags: polymer

I had a component with two properties hinted as booleans. And I noticed that with the attribute reflection activated, using one as a string will break the other (chrome stable and canary).

```
<polymer-element name='any-name' attributes='attr1  boolattr'> 
  <template>
  boolattr: <i>{{boolattr}}</i>, attr1: <i>{{attr1}}</i>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('any-name',{
      publish:{
        attr1 :{value:true,reflect:true},
      },
      boolattr:false
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
<any-name attr1="false" boolattr></any-name>
```

I know that `attr1` shouldn't be used like this, but i'm still curious about what's happening there. Why boolattr isn't recognized anymore ?

Here the functional Jsbin : http://jsbin.com/qaroqa/1/edit

**Last thing**, I noticed that once ready the HTML would look like this

```
<any-name boolattr=""></any-name>
```

I guess what happen is that `attr1` is interpreted as a boolean (because hinted as one) and reflected back as a falsy boolean which mean removed. Is that correct ?